# Factory and IOC together - how to use then both?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, autofac, factory-pattern

So I have this application where Im using IOC (autofac). In the mean time I found myself in position where I need a factory. Inside the factory I create new objects that has dependencies - so now I'm wondering, how could I marry these?

```
public class SubscriptionHandlerFactory : ISubscriptionHandlerFactory
{
    public ISubscriptionHandler GetProvider(StreamType streamType)
    {
        switch (streamType)
        {
            case StreamType.Rss:
                return new RssSubscriptionHandler(null,null,null,null);
            case StreamType.Person:
                return new PersonSubscriptionHandler(null, null, null, null);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(streamType), streamType, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inject the IoC container into the factory and then use the methods exposed on it to acquire an instance of the concrete type you want. Then the container will resolve the other dependencies for you.

Comment: @MartinCostello that's a service locator, largely considered an anti-pattern, even if done within a factory.

Comment: Are you certain you NEED a factory?  Why are you certain that you can't allow the IoC container to build the object dependency graph for you?

Comment: Sorry for late response David, what do you propose to avoid factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [named and keyed service](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) and retrieve instances using `IIndex<TKey, TService>`

Registration could look like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<RssHandler>().Keyed<ISubscriptionHandler>(StreamType.Rss);
builder.RegisterType<PersonHandler>().Keyed<ISubscriptionHandler>(StreamType.Person);
builder.RegisterType<SubscriptionHandlerFactory>().As<ISubscriptionHandlerFactory>();
```

and factory like this :

```
public class SubscriptionHandlerFactory : ISubscriptionHandlerFactory
{
    public SubscriptionHandlerFactory(IIndex<StreamType, ISubscriptionHandler> handlers)
    {
        this._handlers = handlers;
    }

    private readonly IIndex<StreamType, ISubscriptionHandler> _handlers;

    public ISubscriptionHandler GetProvider(StreamType streamType)
    {
        return this._handlers[streamType];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. I also can abstract away the IIndex, for sake of being not attached to autofac.

Comment: Actually the factory has just become the abstraction over autofac, from perspective of customer of that factory - that's even better!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use IoC to abstract away the instantiation of objects forever. At some point you are going to have to create a concrete instance (either inside your factory or your IoC container)

You could either inject your autofac container into your factory or, since your factory itself implements an interface then you can inject different versions of your factory into what ever class might require them (e.g. if you needed a different factory for unit testing purposes)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. Kind of. Since I didnt want to take dependency on Autofac it self I was torn. But thanks to @martin-costello it came to me that maybe I dont need to take autofac, but the build in IDependencyResolver which is less evil. Since I was unable to register autofac as IDependencyResolver I register DependencyResolver as IDependencyResolver. One more step closer. Since registration happens before autofac DependencyResolver.SetResolver happens I needed to use Lazy which finally solves my problem.

Here's code (or at least the best solution I found out)

```
// other registration
builder.RegisterType<RssSubscriptionHandler>();
builder.RegisterType<PersonSubscriptionHandler>();
// even more registration here

builder.RegisterType<SubscriptionHandlerFactory>()
       .As<ISubscriptionHandlerFactory>()
       .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(Lazy<IDependencyResolver>), 
                      new Lazy<IDependencyResolver>(() => DependencyResolver.Current)));
```

Then factory changes to this (before cleanup):

```
public class SubscriptionHandlerFactory : ISubscriptionHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly Lazy<IDependencyResolver> resolver;

    public SubscriptionHandlerFactory(Lazy<IDependencyResolver> resolver)
    {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    public ISubscriptionHandler GetProvider(StreamType streamType)
    {
        switch (streamType)
        {
            case StreamType.Rss:
                return (ISubscriptionHandler)this.resolver.Value.GetService(typeof(RssSubscriptionHandler));
            case StreamType.Person:
                return (ISubscriptionHandler)this.resolver.Value.GetService(typeof(PersonSubscriptionHandler));
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(streamType), streamType, null);
        }
    }
}
```

This for now is the best/clean/less evil/less specific/abstract/whatever solution that I was able to figure out. Any comment welcome.